# Expectation value of operator - python

Tags: programming, quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises

I am suposed to solve following problem:

> Calculate the probability $P_n(x > X)$ that a particle in then n-th eigenstate is found at a position with an x-value larger than X.  Here it is convenient to formulate  it  as  an  expectation  value  of  an  operator.   We  make  an  operator $P(x > X)$ which is a matrix with unity on the diagonal if $x > X$.

To do this  I  used  the  command `>` which  returns True if  the  number  on  the  left  is larger than the one on the right and False otherwise. To turn the True or False into 0 or 1 we use the method `astype(int)` on the `NumPy` array, which we then transform to an operator.T ake  a  few  values  of X,  e.g. X=  3,  5,  and  7,  and  plot $P_n(x > X)$  as  a function of $n$ (make sure that the box size $L$ is somewhat larger than $X$).

The excercise continues as follow

> Explain what you see:  Why is it low when $n$ is small?  At which value ofnwould you expect $P_n(x > X)$ to grow from a small to a large value? Hint :which energy would it require classically?

**My question is: How do I find the expectation value of the operator?**

Comment: Hello! As you must know the expectation value of an operator $A$ in the state $\psi$ is $\langle A \rangle_{\psi} = \langle \psi |A| \psi \rangle$. I believe from this you can use matrix multiplication in Python, did you try? Also, if you are familiar with Qiskit, there are some ways to get the expectation value, if you are interested :)

Answer (score 1):

The [expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_value_(quantum_mechanics)) of an observable $A$ with respect to the state $|\psi \rangle$ can be calculated as:
$$\langle \psi |A| \psi \rangle = Tr( \langle \psi | A| \psi \rangle) = Tr( A|\psi \rangle \langle \psi|) = Tr(A \rho) = Tr(\rho A)$$

$\rho = | \psi \rangle \langle \psi |$ is the [density matrix formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix) of $|\psi\rangle$.

Now, if giving a $|\psi\rangle$ and $A$, and you want to calculate $\langle \psi | A| \psi \rangle$ in Python, you can do it as follows:

```
import numpy as np 
norm_psi = [1., 1., 1., 1.]/np.linalg.norm(psi)
A  = np.matrix( '3,0,0,1; 0,-1,0,0; 0,0,-1,0; 1,0,0,1' )
print('Operator A=\n', A)
expectation  = np.inner(np.conj(norm_psi).T, np.matmul(A,norm_psi) ) #Calculate <norm_psi|A|norm_psi> 
print('\n expectation value calculated by <norm_psi|A|norm_psi> :\n ' , expectation)
#-------
rho =  np.outer(norm_psi, np.conj(norm_psi) )
expectation = np.trace(rho*A)
print('\n expectation value calculated by Tr(rho*A):\n ' , expectation)
```

The output would be something like:

```
Operator A=
 [[ 3  0  0  1]
 [ 0 -1  0  0]
 [ 0  0 -1  0]
 [ 1  0  0  1]]

 expectation value calculated by <norm_psi|A|norm_psi> :
  [[1.]]

 expectation value calculated by Tr(rho*A):
  1.0
```

---

You can use Qiskit to do this as well. And it is quite simply if your operator $A$ is straight forward decomposition of Pauli strings, like $A = Z\otimes Z$ or $A = X \otimes Z$ etc. For instance, if
$$A =  X \otimes Z = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0& 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

and $\psi$ is the same as previously: $|\psi \rangle = \dfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Note that this state can be prepared on a quantum circuit as:

[image]

then you can calculate the expectation as:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.aqua.operators import X, Y, Z, I
from qiskit.aqua.operators import StateFn

operator = X ^ Z  #Note that ^ represents tensor product 
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
qc.h(1)
psi = StateFn(qc) 
expectation = (~psi @ operator @ psi).eval()
print('expectation value is:', expectation)
```

output: `expectation value is: 0j`

Which is what you would expect by looking at the matrix form of $A$.